# Prototype Rounded Corners

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, rounded-corners

I am using http://nurey.com/corners.html with Prototype framework and trying to get some rounded corner action happening.

However, the script I am using

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
  if($$('header')!=null) {
    $('header').Effect.Corner("5px");
  }
});
```

Doesn't appear to actually make the corners work ? Can anyone help ?

**Edit:** The error I get is

```
$("header").Effect is undefined
```

Comment: Maybe you already know, but most of browsers (except of IE, of course) support round borders. Take a look at http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Comment: hey thanks - yeah IE is the problem :) already using these on FF and Webkit. But trying to fix IE ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
new Effect.Corner($('header'), '5px');
```